# Only let HTML continue once all images have loaded

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I recycled a lot of code from an old JS project I made back in the very beginning of my learning process, and back then I knew nothing about DOM events. Specifically in this case, `onload`. What I am looking for is someway to only let the website begin to run once all images have loaded, without putting everything into one big `onload` function, or rewriting all my code. Is there anyway to do this?

```
<img src="placeholder.png" onload="continue()" width="100" height="100">
<script>
   function continue() {
      //This is where I am stuck
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to set the `display` property of the body to `none` when the page is loading, and then have `continue()` make it visible.

CSS:

```
body {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
function continue() {
    document.body.style.display = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the images aren't going to be dynamically added to DOM  you can simply just do the followingaIf the images aren't going to be dynamically added to DOM  you can simply just do the following

```
<html>
<body style="display: none;">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200" alt="">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="">
  <script>
    const imageCollection = Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName('img'));
    const promisifier = (imageNode) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        imageNode.addEventListener("load", () => {
          console.log('image loaded', imageNode);
          resolve('Loaded')
          });
      })
    }

    Promise.all(imageCollection.map(img => promisifier(img))).then((resp)=>{
      document.body.style.display = 'block';
      console.log('All images completed Loading');
    })
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

If images are going to be dynamically added you could go for Mutation Observer, let me know if thats the case will add that too.